# jQuery Adding and Removing Rows Trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, rows

I'm trying to create a new use for an already implemented tool we use here at work, but I'm very sure I'm doing something wrong.

I can't figure out how to make it delete a row. And even more, I can figure out how to clone everything within .pt-entry, and have it replicated inside of the incremental .pt-entry...but without the user filled in info.

Hopefully this makes sense.

You can check out my [Pen here](http://cdpn.io/ccc85f9afe25977bca9b414945df8174), but here's the code breakdown for the rest of yous:

HTML:

```
<table class="manage-pt" id="0">
    <tr class="pt-entry">
        <td class="pt-toggle-group">
            <input type="button" class="pt-button togPTbutton" value="?" />
            <input type="button" class="pt-button addPTbutton" value="+" /> 
            <input type="button" class="pt-button delPTbutton" value="-" />
        </td>
        <td class="pt-values">
            <div>
                <input type="text" class="vendor" placeholder="Vendor Name" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea class="ptCode" name="ptCode" placeholder="Pixel Tag Code" ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="page-select">
                <select>
                    <option value="AllPages">All Pages</option>
                    <option value="HomePage">HomePage</option>
                    <option value="VehicleDetailsPage">VehicleDetailsPage</option>
                    <option value="VehicleSearchResults">VehicleSearchResults</option>
                    <option value="ContactUsForm">ContactUsForm</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="area-checkboxes">
                <p class="wheretosave">Where?</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="head" /><label for="head">Head</label> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="body" /><label for="body">Body</label>
            </div>
            <div class="save-pt">
                <input value="SAVE" type="submit" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
// HIDES CURRENT PT & CHANGES TOGGLE BUTTON ICON WHEN CLICKED
$('.togPTbutton').click(function(){
    $('.pt-values').slideToggle(25, function() {
        if ($('.pt-values').is(':hidden')) {
            $('input.togPTbutton').val('?');
        }else{
            $('input.togPTbutton').val('?');
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('.manage-pt'),
        rows = $(table).find('tr'),
        rowCount = $(rows).length,
        addedRow = $(document.createElement('tr')),
        addButton = $('.addPTbutton'),
        removeButton = $('.delPTbutton');

    function addRow(){
        var thisRow = $(addedRow).clone(true);
        $(thisRow).attr('class','.pt-entry-' + rowCount);
        rowCount += 1;
        $(thisRow).html('<td>row</td>');
        $(table).append(thisRow);
    }

    function removeRow(){
        var items = $(table).querySelectorAll('tr');
        if (rowCount > 1) {
            $(table).remove(items[rowCount - 1]);
            rowCount -= 1;
        }else{
            alert('CANNOT DELETE LAST ROW');
        }
    }

    addButton.click(function(e){
        addRow();
    });

    removeButton.click(function(e){
        removeRow();
    });
});
```

Should look close to something like this mockup ...
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think I found your problem. You are trying to call `$(table).querySelectorAll('tr')`. `.querySelectorAll` is a javascript function that you are using with a JQuery selector. This is where your `removeRow()` function bombs. Try commenting that line out. Then, you will need to find a new way to select the last row, which can easily be done with this:

```
$(table).find('tr:last').remove();
```

Final form:

```
function removeRow(){
    //var items = $(table).querySelectorAll('tr');
    if (rowCount > 1) {
        //$(table).remove(items[rowCount - 1]);
        $(table).find('tr:last').remove();
        rowCount -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('CANNOT DELETE LAST ROW');
    }
}
```

If you want this to work in IE8 and older, you can use this JQuery since you have the number of rows:

```
$(table).find('tr').eq(rowCount - 1).remove();
```

in place of:

```
$(table).find('tr:last').remove();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Em8Q5/2/

EDIT: ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Alright, I found a solution being able to delete the current row.

First, allow a parameter into your removeRow function and switch the selector to use `closest`:

```
function removeRow(currRow){
    //var items = $(table).querySelectorAll('tr');
    if (rowCount > 1) {
        //$(table).remove(items[rowCount - 1]);
        currRow.closest('tr').remove();
        rowCount -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('CANNOT DELETE LAST ROW');
    }
}
```

Then you will need to modify your `.click` function so that it will change dynamically as you add/remove rows/buttons. Also, note the parameter so it knows which row's button is clicked.

```
//removeButton.click(function(e){
$('body').on("click", ".delPTbutton", function(e) {
    removeRow($(this)); //Note the parameter that we added so it knows which row to remove
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Em8Q5/3/

Comment: That does work great, however is :last able to be used in IE 8+? I ask because I'm still learning and I had some pseudo selectors in there original, and was told by someone to remove them because those are CSS3 selectors which might not work on all browsers.

Comment: Another thing too which I just thought about. When .pt-entry gets cloned or copied, EVERYTHING will be inside of that new entry as well. So I wouldn't be targeting the tr:last to delete. I should be targeting THIS as in the tr.pt-entry-x to be removed.

Comment: I added a solution for IE8 and older that does not use the `:last` CSS selector. Also, since you clone a new `tr` and append only that tr when you add a row, remove just the last tr should be fine, unless I am missing something.

Comment: That method is way better, thanks!
I attached an image to illustrate what I'm talking about. Basically every new addition of .pt-entry will also have a new set of toggle/add/remove buttons that correspond to that row and that row only. The add buttons will always add a row in the very last place. However the remove button will only remove the row it's located in. That make better sense?

Comment: Doing what you want is somewhat complicated because you are adding and removing rows with an "onclick" function. The reason for this is that your onclick functions loads once, when the page first loads. So when you add a new row with buttons, the onclick for those will not work. Looking into alternatives/work-arounds for you.

Comment: Oh wow. I had no idea. thanks a ton for the effort. You're definitely helping a lot.

Comment: Not a problem. I think I found a solution. I updated my answer to show it and also added a new JSFiddle with it working (even though the buttons are flat for some reason, but still work).

Answer (score 0):

I check up your code using chrome developer tool and when i clicked the delPTbutton button to remove last row it showed an error in your removeRow Method , The Error Message Is :

(Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'querySelectorAll')

The Issue Here Is That 'querySelectorAll' Is One Of javascript base api but you use it after a jquery object.

Consider Using $(table).find('tr') Instead .

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thank you @Chad for your help. You were seriously a life saver.

I took what you did, one step further in this new version of the code:

[New CodePen](http://cdpn.io/28d13fec99066bc287bf2d0700f474ce)

However I now have a very js minor issue. I have it set to turn the ".vendor" input to read only when the relevant stack is closed, however I need to target something other than ".vendor", because it's effecting each clones ".vendor" as well.

Would it be something like:
`$(this).parent().next().child().child();`?